# How to replace words in a paragraph after a specified interval? with js

Tags: javascript, replace, settimeout

Say I have a paragraph like this; `<p class="some-text">This is just a random paragraph for example use. This is just a random paragraph for example use. This is just a random paragraph for example use. This is just a random paragraph for example use. This is just a random paragraph for example use.</p>`

And I want to replace all "paragraph" with "text" 
and I know that one can manipulate *strings* using `.replace(" paragraph", " text")` , but this is a whole paragraph. I also want the text to change with a delay of 5 seconds but what I get in return for the code below is `textToChange.replace is not a function`. How can I go about this with a whole paragraph?

```
function replaceWords() {
  const toChange = document.querySelector("some-text");

  const fixedWords = toChange
    .replace(" paragraph", " text")


  toChange.innerHTML = fixedWords;
}
setTimeout(replaceWords, 5000);
```

Comment: You are calling the replace function on a Dom element not on a string. You should add . innerHTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need `innerHTML` of the paragraph before replacing and use `/textToBeReplaced/g` to replace all occurrence. Also in `document.querySelector` you have to pass `.` with class name like `document.querySelector(".some-text");`

```js
function replaceWords() {
  const toChange = document.querySelector(".some-text");
  const fixedWords = toChange.innerHTML.trim().replace(/paragraph/g, " text")
  toChange.innerHTML = fixedWords;
}
setTimeout(replaceWords, 5000);
```

```html
<p class="some-text">This is just a random paragraph for example use. This is just a random paragraph for example use. This is just a random paragraph for example use. This is just a random paragraph for example use. This is just a random paragraph for example use.</p>
```

Comment: Why `.innerHTML`? The paragraph only contains text. And why `.trim()`? And why the space before `text`?

Comment: yeah, I noticed first after that I forgot to pass . with the class name in the document.querySelector, but I understand it now! so thank you very much for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch text (innerHTML) from element:

```
function replaceWords() {
  const toChange = document.querySelector("some-text");

  const fixedWords = toChange.innerHTML.replace(" paragraph", " text")
  toChange.innerHTML = fixedWords;
}
setTimeout(replaceWords, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I get in return for the code below is `toChange.replace is not a function.`

That is because `toChange` is not a string, it is an HTML element.

Replace

```js
const fixedWords = toChange
    .replace(" paragraph", " text")
```

With

```js
const fixedWords = toChange.innerHTML
    .replace(" paragraph", " text")
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector("some-text");` will be `document.querySelector(".some-text");` for class need to add `.` before class name

`toChange.replace` is not a function it will `toChange.innerHTML`

```js
function replaceWords() {
  const toChange = document.querySelector(".some-text");

  const fixedWords = toChange.innerHTML.replace(" paragraph", " text")
  toChange.innerHTML = fixedWords;
}
setTimeout(replaceWords, 5000);
```

```html
<p class="some-text">This is just a random paragraph for example use. This is just a random paragraph for example use. This is just a random paragraph for example use. This is just a random paragraph for example use. This is just a random paragraph for example use.</p>
```